# Google Search is always grouping stackoverflow results. How to disable?

Tags: google-search, google-chrome

Since the beginning of this year, I think, Google Search started to group any programming-related search results from **stackoverflow**:

[image]

Due to this I can't see all stackoverflow results on the first page, I need to make an additional click on `More results from stackoverflow.com` link and it's annoying. I literally can feel how this extra action spends my energy and time.

*I understand that Google probably wants to give a chance to other sites. But I'm not interested in them. Usually they just copy answers from the best question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. That clones can be even called like stackblablalba.*

The question is how to setup Google Search to show stackoverflow results first? Is it possible to add specific search bar in the Google Chrome to perform search with `site:stackoverflow.com` option?